# What is the difference between 省 and 省份?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

Two sentences "他也算是我省的名人" and "他也算是我省份的名人", is the second sentence wrong? If it is wrong, why?

Comment: My feeling is that the difference is akin to 月 vs. 月份, or 'house' vs. 'household' in English - the former can be used to address a particular instance while the latter is usually used to express the concept itself, although for the particular pair (省 and 省份), the difference is of little significance and they are interchangeable in most cases.

Comment: @NS.X. But "他定于四月份回国" is correct!

Comment: That's right, there is a large overlap in meaning and usage. The difference was referring to the non-overlapped part.

Comment: @NS.X. I think my question is: in which case they are not interchangeable?

Comment: I don't know for sure, that's why I only left a comment and it started with 'my feeling is'. I am also looking forward to a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, it's OK.

PS: `省份` means `province`, but it can't be used with specific names. For example we can say `山东省`, but not `山东省份`.

Some examples: (from http://www.fantizi5.com/ciyuzaoju/zj23292.html)

1、辽宁是中国的一个省份。
2、有些工作地点遥远，在另一个省份。
3、并不奇怪的是，这些省份都位于中国较富裕的东部。
4、开始的时候，我向其他省份的亲戚朋友们询问，或者向他们传达我的信息。
5、但是，瓶颈已经出现了，一些省份报告说电力短缺，并且煤的库存量很低。
6、有些省份报道了用电短缺和煤炭低库存的现象。
7、在2004年总统选举中，该家族帮助她赢得了在这一省份的绝大多数选票。
8、在荷兰的12个省份中，每个省都会有一双特别设计的木屐鞋。
9、有报道说今年在沿海省份中因为劳动力短缺和工人要求提高工资，工资也大幅上升。
10、在中国的一些省份，其比例史无前例的达到了130比100。
11、我和妻子住在不同的省份。
12、中国政府压低了煤油和其他自然资源的价格，牺牲了内地出产这些资源的省份的利益，造福了使用这些资源的沿海出口商。
13、在收到卫生部的进一步信息之前，世卫组织将发布详情，以表格显示所有24例的发病日期、结果和省份。
14、在2007年，中国最北部的省份黑龙江报告了夏季干旱，这几乎是闻所未闻的事情，通常这时候是汛期。
15、其中许多城市位于远离北京和上海的欠发达的内陆省份。
16、在接下来的四天时间里我们要穿越五个省份，游历其中的三个。
17、在改革税制中，你们和下面的省份没有遇到任何比较强烈的对抗吗？
18、我们已呼吁其他省份的人们加入进来。
19、但是俄罗斯方面没有作出回应，并且一直在轰炸格鲁吉亚这个要求分离的省份周边的一些地区。

Comment: as nouns 省 and 省份 mean the same，in general，perhaps， however，for well known reasons a ２ character word can be understood more easily and quickly than a single character word （although not necessarily in the present case）
作名词＂省＂ 和 ＂省份＂的意思是相同的。但一般来说，也许出于众所周知的原因双音词比单音词更清楚，也可理解得更容易而快速（虽然不一定是在目前的情况下）。

Comment: None of your examples justifies the usage of `我省份`..

Comment: @WangDingwei http://ah.anhuinews.com/system/2008/03/19/001972665.shtml http://fj.qq.com/a/20120731/000051.htm http://bbs.chinaacc.com/forum-2-5/topic-1426905.html

Comment: got me. still i don't like it being used like this. Maybe it's just me...

Comment: I would consider it as an editor's error. @songyuanyao

Answer (score 1):

A common way to say it should be "他也算是**我们省**的名人".

我省 is an established idiom, meaning "our province". It's a formal word and is often used in government reports and political agendas. Similar phrases include 我国, 我县, etc. You don't see normal people use them often.

省份 usually refers to one or several provinces in relation to the whole country, so you usually don't use it with a personal pronoun, like 我的省份, 我们省份, 你们省份, etc.

If you google 我省份, all you find is the funny 我省份证, which should be 我身份证 of course.

Comment: I don't see the logical relation between "省份 usually refers to one or several provinces in relation to the whole country" and "possessive pronoun+省份 is not okay". Can you explain more?

Comment: Sorry i did an awful job explaining it. There isn't really much reason to it. Being idiomatic requires no reason.. You just watch how people use it and follow the conventions. 我省份 is not in wide use, so you may want to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a simple induction on my daily uses, it seems to me that 省 is mostly used to reference a specific province, while 省份 is used for a general  province or the concept itself.

For example,

这是一个贫穷的省份。(This is a poor province.) 省份 can be used since we are talking about one province (considering the indefinite article in the English translation may be helpful?), and 省 is OK as well.

在我们省有很多 IT 公司。(In our province there are lots of IT companies.) 省份 would be strange if it was used here.

If you are not sure when speaking or writing, using 省 will be OK.

Comment: "省 is mostly used to reference a specific province" -- Not true. 长江中下游的六个省发生了洪涝灾害。

Comment: @Wang Dingwei  Is "在一个省份就有很多IT公司" grammatically correct?

Comment: no problem, but you said *mostly* which may not be true

Comment: Sorry, I am more confused. According to the above explanation, it looks like "省" can be used in both specific provinces and non-specific provinces. But "省份" can be used both in specific provinces and non-specific provinces too. The sentence "在一个省份就有很多IT公司" is an example of "non-specific". The example of specific provinces is: 千百年来，这条河就这样默默地滋养着这个贫瘠的省份。 So in the end, what is the difference between "省" and "省份"?

Answer (score -1):

the 2nd one is right.

when they("省"and "省份") mean "province", you can  think they are  the same, otherwise not.For example, there can  be "省略"  but no  "省份略"